# How should I go about solving the following limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How do I solve the following limit?

$$\lim _{x\to \:1} \frac{\left(1-x^{1/2}\right)\left(1-x^{1/3}\right)\cdots \left(1-x^{1/n}\right)}{(1-x)^{n-1}}$$

The solution should be 0, but the source isn't reliable.

Thank you.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889127/tough-limit-to-evaluate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cdots=\lim_{x\to1 }\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{x^{\frac{1}{k}}-1}{(x-1)}\underset{(1)}{=}\prod_{k=2}^n\lim_{x\to1 }\frac{x^{\frac{1}{k}}-1}{(x-1)}\underset{(2)}{=}\prod_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{n!}$$

*Justifications:*

$(1):$ Because the product is finite.

$(2):$ Because $$\lim_{x\to1 }\frac{x^{\frac{1}{k}}-1}{x-1}=\frac{d x^{\frac{1}{k}}}{dx}\Big|_{x=1}=\frac{1}{k}1^{\frac{1}{k}-1}=\frac{1}{k}$$

Answer (score 0):

The given equation is same as
$$\lim_{x\to1}\prod_{i=2}^n {1-x^{1/i}\over1-x}.$$
By using
$$\lim_{a\to1}{1-a\over1-a^m}=\lim_{a\to1}{1\over1+a+\dots+a^{m-1}}={1\over m},$$
we get
$${1\over n!}.$$
Does the answer really $0$? Or am I wrong? Don't you have $(n\to\infty)$ in addition?

Comment: Shouldn't the denominator in the product be $(1-x)^{n-1}$ not $(1-x)$?

Comment: @EulCan But it is in $\prod_{i=2}^n$, so we multiply it $n-1$ times.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for explaining. I figured I'd missed something like that :)